# Strange artifacts when ray casting a volume

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, raycasting

So I am writing a volume ray caster (for the first time ever) in Java, learning from the code of the great VTK toolkit written in C.

Everything works almost exactly like VTK, except I get this strange artifacts, looking like elevation lines on the volume. I've noticed that VTK also shows them when manipulating the image, but they disappear when the image is static.

I've looked though the code multiple times, and can't find the source of the artifacts. Maybe it is something simple a computer graphics expert knows from the top of his head? :)

More info on my implementation

- I am using the gradient method for normal calculations (a standard from what I've found on the internet)
- I am using trilinear interpolation for ray point values
- This "elevation line" artifacts look like value rounding errors, but I can't find any in my code
- Increasing the resolution of the render does not solve the problem
- The artifacts do not seem to be "facing" any fixed direction, like the camera position
- I'm not attaching the code since it is huge :)

[image: Example image]
EDIT (ray composite loop)

```
while (Geometry.pointInsideCuboid(cuboid, position) && result.a > MINIMAL_OPACITY) {
        if (currentVoxel.notEquals(previousVoxel)) {
            final float value = VoxelUtils.interpolate(position, voxels, buffer);

            color = colorLUT.getColor(value);
            opacity = opacityLUT.getOpacityFromLut(value);

            if (enableShading) {
                final Vector3D normal = VoxelUtils.getNormal(position, voxels, buffer);
                final float cos = normal.dot(light.fixedDirection);
                final float gradientOpacity = cos < 0 ? 0 : cos;

                opacity *= gradientOpacity;

                if(cos > 0)
                    color = color.clone().shade(cos, colorLUT.diffuse, colorLUT.specular);
            }

            previousVoxel.setTo(currentVoxel);
        }

        if(opacity > 0)
            result.accumulate(color, opacity);

        position.add(rayStep);
        currentVoxel.fromVector(position);
    }
```

Comment: How do you compute a color of single pixel? Do you raycast through the volume and blend the values or do you use just a first hit as in a solid objects?

Comment: @kolenda I blend (accumulate the color) - I've based my implemetation on the Trilinear Unshaded ray composition from VTK - https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/Volume/vtkVolumeRayCastCompositeFunction.cxx#L745

Comment: I don't understand how do you get this orange color. The banding itself is fine - we can fix it with some tricks but I need to understand what I see first :). Are you using RGB colored voxel field? What colors are mainly there? Could you show us your inner loop, that computes single pixel color? You may also try to end computations after first hit - no blending, just return the first non-0 color and see if you still have this banding.

Comment: @kolenda I've attached the main ray composite loop - I'm using a voxel field with a color lut and opacity lut. I'm using exactly the same data in VTK btw :)